# Compatibility between Doxygen and DocBlox

Tags: drupal, documentation, doxygen, docblox

I'm in the process of choosing an API Documentation Generator tool for a project in Drupal.

The developers of the Drupal Core use Doxygen: http://drupal.org/node/1354

Reading their comment formating conventions it seems to me that Doxygen and DocBlox use tags that are compatible between them.

Is this assumption correct?

Meaning that if I create my documentation following indistinctly the Doxygen documentation or the DocBlox documentation it would allow me to generate documentation with either of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately DocBlox was developed independently of Doxygen, so the set of tags both support are not the same and, worse, some tags have the same name but a different meaning/function (examples are @package and @var).